# How to detect whether it's the same StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my app, I have a `NotificationListenerService` that listens to all notifications. I have a `StatusBarNotification` field that is assigned when some notification is posted and nullified when it is removed. Before nullifying, I have to check whether or not it is the same `StatusBarNotification` that I have assigned before. However, the check with `==` operator does not work as expected even though it's exactly the same notification. So how can I compare them?

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    private StatusBarNotification targetNotification;

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification notification) {
        if (targetNotification == null && notification.isClearable()) {
            targetNotification = notification;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification notification) {
        System.out.println("removed noti: " + notification.getPackageName() + ", " + notification.getPostTime()+", "+notification.getId()+", "+notification.getUserId());
        System.out.println("target noti: " + targetNotification.getPackageName() + ", " + targetNotification.getPostTime()+", "+targetNotification.getId()+", "+targetNotification.getUserId());
        System.out.println(notification == targetNotification);

        if (notification == targetNotification) {
            targetNotification = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

> removed noti: com.samepackage, 1412915524994, -99, 0
>
> target noti: com.samepackage, 1412915524994, -99, 0
>
> false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `onNotificationRemoved (StatusBarNotification sbn)`:

> Parameters
>
> sbn:  A data structure encapsulating at least the original
>   information (tag and id) and source (package name) used to post the
>   Notification that was just removed.

So I think to compare two notifications, we need to compare their tag, id, and package name:

```
    if (notification.getTag().equals(targetNotification.getTag()) && 
        notification.getId() == targetNotification.getId() && 
        notification.getPackageName().equals(targetNotification.getPackageName())) {
                targetNotification = null;
    }
```

Edit: Be careful, notification tags can be null! (So, the code above might throw NPE). Make sure to control it.

Answer (score 1):

== compare objecs which point to same memory location.( 
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)
so instead of comparing to objects please compare it's id value. this might be solve your problem.

```
 if (notification.getId() == targetNotification.getId()) {
             targetNotification = null;
     }
```

Comment: But are you sure `getId()` return unique values for different notification? I have not found any documentation about this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29

in notify method parameter id 
id  An identifier for this notification unique within your application.

Comment: `unique within your application`, but not unique for several applications I think? Which means a notification from Facebook and a notification from Hangouts may have the same id value right?

Comment: k i got your problem. yes it might be